# Confusion in the definition of a generator set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $B\subset V$ a base of $V$. Now let $S \subset V$ be a subspace of $V$, such that $B \cap S = \emptyset$. My question is: can I say that $B$ generates $S$? Or, in order to say that a set $A$ is a generator of a subspace, does $A$ have to be contained in that subspace?

I know this is a bit of a silly question, but I really got confused with the definition... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator of a vector subspace $S$ is by definition a subset $A\subset S$ such that every vector $w\in S$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $A$. Therefore, if $B\cap S=\emptyset$, we don't have $B\subset S$, so $B$ can't be a generator of $S$.

A different thing is to say that $B$ can also generate the elements of $S$, which is trivially true, since $B$ is a generator of $V$ (bases are generators), so it can generate any element of $V$, hence the same for $S$, since it is a vector subspace.

It's a matter of terminology, but the common thing is to talk about a generator of a vector subspace, also called a spanning set, in which case we must have it contained in the vector subspace it's generating.

Answer (score 0):

See this example to grasp:

We know that $e_1=(1,0)'$ and $e_2=(0,1)'$ are generators for $\mathbb R^2$ and if $S$ the subspace generated by $A=\{e_1+e_2\}$, then this shows how the basis are related: $B\cap S=\varnothing$ and $A\subset S$.